# Rails Dynamic SQL with variables: undefined method find_by_SQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, dynamic-sql, find-by-sql

I have a complex SQL statement that crosses several tables. I wish to pass variables into this statement dynamically and return the data in a JSON format. Ihave tested and know the query works in PHPMyAdmin and have placed it within the manSearch method in my requests class. At present, the below query simply remarks: `undefined method find_by_SQL`. I know from documentation that the fin_by_SQl does exist in my version 4.0.1.

How can I make this work?

```
def mainSearch

    @results = Campaign.find_by_SQL("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...)

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @results }
    end     
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `find_by_sql` not `find_by_SQL`.

Comment: I did not know it was case sensitive